# Can not add Woodworking to "Your Communities"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I'm not able to add Woodworking to my list for "Your Communities" on the top menu bar. When I click "edit", search and add the site. It does show that it was added to the list, but if I refresh the page it's gone.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Working fine here; are you using a particular OS/browser, so that I can try to reproduce the issue? Also: did you hit "Save"?

Comment: @MarcGravell lol, clicking "save" was the trick. I didn't even see the button since my list was so long. Thanks.

Comment: It is a an interesting point, though; we don't always enforce "save" buttons - a lot of similar changes *just happen*

Comment: @MarcGravell for me the action of clicking the "add" button should be final. I've added the new item so why do I have to also save it. It's not like I'm editing a word document. If I added it by mistake then I can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember, I had to close out my browser tab and come back to get the beta sites to 'stick'.

Comment: You can see in the comments that this is just a matter of not clicking save. Can you add status-bydesign tag to this one?